Can't call Rest Service spring boot in github actions
The following error occurs when trying to call Rest api using RestTemplate in a JunitTest
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:0/print/invoice": Connection refused
    at se.winassist.PrintingAppTest.testGetPrintableDocumentEN(PrintingAppTest.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:0/print/invoice": Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at se.winassist.PrintingAppTest.testGetPrintableDocumentEN(PrintingAppTest.java:73)

Here is the code :
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PrintingApp.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class PrintingAppTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;

    @Test
    public void testGetPrintableDocumentSE() {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("siteId", "123456789");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Invoice invoice = Invoice.builder().invoiceNumber(1234).language("SE").build();
        try {
            RequestEntity<Invoice> requestEntity =
                    new RequestEntity<Invoice>(invoice,
                            requestHeaders,
                            HttpMethod.POST,
                            new URI(""));
            ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/print/invoice",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity,
                    Resource.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

I dont know why it works during mvn clean install but not in GitHub Actions pipeline

It does not matter if i specify a port or use random port.

it works fine when running mvn clean install locally but not in github action
